# How can i call an non static method of Abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

How can i call an non static method of Abstract class, without using its sub class or extends it because abstract class and sub class is too complex so i do not want to cause any side effect.

for example concrete static methods of an abstract class can be call with class name an dot operator, without creating sub class. Similar is there any way to call a non static method.

i just want to run a method and i do not want run any other code. i tried to use reflection but it requires instance

Comment: in short: You can't.

Comment: no, there isn't, since you can't instantiate an abstract class. You will need to create a subclass,  that's the only way

Answer (score 6):

Abstract classes are **abstract**, meaning that you cannot create an instance of the class.

Therefore, you **cannot call instance methods** of an abstract class.

```
public abstract class Foo {
   static void bar();
   void foobar();
}
```

you can call `Foo.bar()` as it is not an instance method (meaning that it does not require an instance of the class) but you cannot call `foobar()` since you cannot do `new Foo().foobar()`.

```
Foo.bar(); // OK, we don't need an instance.

Foo foo = new Foo(); // Not OK - we cannot instantiate an abstract class.
foo.foobar();
```

---

For a way to create an instance of an abstract class **without having to use derived classes**, see [ernest_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51648419/7571171) utilizing **anonymous classes**.

Comment: As @ernest_k menationed in his answer, the use of an an anonymous class could also be considered. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @Glains you're right, I added that to my answer (I didn't want to steal and copy ernest's answer though, so I didn't go into details and linked to their answer only).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you can't. You need an instance.

An easy way to create an instance is using an anonymous class:

```
AbstractClass o = new AbstractClass(){
    //implement abstract methods... or just leave stubs
};

o.concreteMethod();
```